# Smith form of an integer matrix in MatLab also providing the permutation matrices

Tags: matlab, math

I need the algorithm to compute the smith normal form of a matrix M. Usually it is described as `M = USV`, see e.g. [SNF on WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form), where my matrices are always of full rank, i.e. `det(S) ~= 0`.

I started in Mathematica, where a nice package provides this algorithm. While there are some implementations around, for example [this one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15247-smith-form-of-a-matrix/content/Smith_Form_V1.m), [this one by Gilbert](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/13728) or [this one using maple](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/120635), I don't have access to maple (I think) and both other implementations either don't compute the matrices `U` and `V` or compute them wronly (try `[5,0;0,5]` in the second implementation, where `U` and `V` should just be unit matrices)

So are there any other implementations available?

Perhaps one following the approach of [this Mathematica package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7081/) (of course analogously in MatLab), because that worked quite well for my needs (when working with Mathematica), but as long as `U` and `V` are provided correctly I don't mind.

Comment: Any reason why you want to switch from Mathematica to Matlab?

Comment: Just curiosity and to have a better comparison to another algorithm that i got from a collegue (which deals with a the topic completely, but can be applied to similar data) - so i would like to compare mine with his - in MatLab :)

Comment: Do you have access to the symbolic math toolbox in matlab? It has an implementation of the [`Smith Normal Form`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/linalg-smithform.html) - though the documentation makes no mention of `U` and `V` either.

Comment: I don't have access to the symbolic math toolbox, but I already saw the documentation (sorry for not mentioning that in the original post) - i don't think it can provide the matrices `U` and `V`

Comment: If you are still interested, I have an implementation.

Comment: That sounds great, I would still be very interested in such an implementation :) @Felix

Comment: If you email me at felix.goldberg AT gmail I will send you the file :)

Comment: Well, there was a misunderstanding in what the Smith normal form was. Thanks again Felix for digging out the old topic, your algorithm does something different; so I am still searching for an algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Matlab 2015b there's `SmithForm` in the Symbolic Math Toolbox documented here

https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/smithform.html

which resolves the mentioned problems.